# When was the first time the number 0 came to mean a multiple of ten?

Tags: mathematics, number-theory, numbers, ancient-india, india

The earliest number notation I can find is the [sexagesimal digit notation of cuneiform](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-cuneiform-notation-of-sexagesimal-digits-Zero-is-represented-by-a-blank-space-The_fig2_314097670#:%7E:text=NoDerivs%203.0%20Unported-,The%20cuneiform%20notation%20of%20sexagesimal%20digits%3A%20Zero%20is%20represented%20by,or%2059%20%3D%2050%20%2B%209). From my understanding of that, in order to make numbers bigger than 60, you would just add the smaller numbers up until you get the number you want. Famously, for [Roman numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals), the digits are 1=I, V=5, X=10, L=50, C=100, and M=1,000. The Romans had ways of expressing bigger numbers, such as by drawing a bar (called a [vinculum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinculum_(symbol)) over the top of the number, and enclosing the numbers on the sides and bottom. Regardless, the number system was still limited at some point in the size of the number it could portray.

Now, I know that [our "Arabic" numerals are actually Indian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu%E2%80%93Arabic_numeral_system#:%7E:text=It%20was%20invented%20between%20the%201st%20and%204th%20centuries%20by%20Indian%20mathematicians.) and they are [positional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation), which means (taken from Wikipedia) "*the contribution of a digit to the value of a number is the value of the digit multiplied by a factor determined by the position of the digit.*" Wikipedia has a really good graphic to make this all more understandable (I think):

[image: positional notation explained]

My understanding of that radix is the base number, and that's how many digits in the numeral system. The digits, are just the numbers in each position, and the position determines which index   number the digit is. Lastly, the index numbers are the place digits, and they determine how many times the digit is multiplied by. For example, the first index position (2) is multiplied by the radix (10) to make that digit equal 20.

So, I THINK I understand positional notation now. And, *I believe* the answer I want to know is what is the first base 10 positional notation, where the number 0 is added onto other digits to make multiples of 10? To be clear, I don't care if the "0" looks anything like our 0, just that it represents nothing, but when added to another number represents a multiple of ten.

****Note: upon further research, I am pretty sure I have found the answer, and I am going to add the answer so I can find it later. If anyone has more to add (or if my answer is wrong) they can add their own answer.

Comment: "When was the first time the number 0 came to mean a multiple of ten?" Not very clear... Do you mean, the first time we "understood" that $0 \times n=0$?

Comment: But your post is a quite long summary of "positional" numbering system: it seems that you understand it quite well. Reversing positions: units, tens, hundreds, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

[Quoting from here](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/HistTopics/Indian_numerals/#:%7E:text=The%20oldest%20dated%20Indian%20document,our%20calendar%20of%20594%20AD.):

> The Indians were the first to develop a base 10 positional system and, considering the date of the Babylonian system, it came very late indeed.

> The oldest dated Indian document which contains a number written in the place-value form used today is a legal document dated 346 in the Chhedi calendar which translates to a date in our calendar of 594 AD.

To be fair, the date on it may be a later addition, so there is some dispute to this. That being said, other examples of the base-10 positional notation being found are dated to 737 AD.